# Declare two types in interface Attributes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, typescript-typings, theme-ui

I need to declare both statements:

```
declare module "react" {
  interface Attributes {
    sx?: ThemeUIStyleObject;
  }
}
```

and

```
declare module "react" {
  interface Attributes {
    sx?: SxStyleProp;
  }
}
```

because if not, theme-ui errors appear in the sx prop.

I've tried this:

```
declare module "react" {
  interface Attributes {
    sx?: ThemeUIStyleObject | SxStyleProp;
  }
}
```

but only works the first Object (ThemeUIStyleObject)

Answer (score 0):

Try `&` to join this two types.

```
sx?: ThemeUIStyleObject & SxStyleProp;
```